# Declaration Null Value in MVC Models for Date Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, null

How to declare null in model for date value, so point is, that I have table where values can be null or some value.

e.g. for String I have do this:

```
    private ICollection<string> _value1;
    [SolrField("value1")]
    public ICollection<string> Value1
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_value1 == null)
            {
                return new Collection<string> { "" };
            }
            else
            {
                return _value1;
            }
        }
        set { _value1 = value; }
    }
```

I have problem to do this code for Date:

```
    [SolrField("date")]
    public ICollection<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

Thanks for any Ideas?

Comment: @akhilles: Why did you tag this question with "objective-c" ??? (And why was the edit approved by 3 people?)

Comment: I did not tag this question with objective-c, editor did it...

Comment: I have removed the objective-C tag. But perhaps you should add the appropriate language tag.

Comment: @MartinR sorry man, I thought it was objective-c question because i saw similarities in syntax

Comment: no problems :) have any idea how to create this variable that can be null

Answer (score 0):

Use Nullable DateTime type

```
[SolrField("date")]
public ICollection<DateTime?> Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: I can't because I use Solr, my Admin has declare DateTime as multivalued=true, I have to build in asp.net that can be null

Comment: Then Return DateTime.MinValue and add logic to treat this MinValue as null. We can't set null for DateTime fields.